# Why the l-map tag overrides a v-navigation-drawer, vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2

Good day,
This way I have the template in one component.

```
<template>
    <v-card fluid>
        <div class="text-xs-center">
            <v-btn outline small fab color="indigo" @click="abrirmodalBusqueda()">
              <v-icon>search</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
            <l-map style="height: 500px; width: 100%" :zoom="zoom" :center="center" @update:center="centerUpdate">
                <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
                <l-marker :lat-lng="marker" >
                    <l-popup>Estoy en estas coordenadas asadsad {{latitud}}</l-popup>
                </l-marker>

                <l-marker v-for="marker in markers" :lat-lng="marker">
                    <l-popup>Estoy en estas coordenadas asadsad {{marker.lat}}
                        <v-flex xs12 sm4 text-xs-center>
                            <div>
                                <v-btn small color="primary" @click="dialogParqueos = true">Seleccionar</v-btn>
                            </div>
                        </v-flex>
                    </l-popup>
                </l-marker>
            </l-map>
        </div>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

When using the property of height in px and not in% I can already visualize the map l-map style = "height: 500px" since if I use 100% the map can not be seen. The problem that when making use of v-navigation-drawer the map is assembled in the following way:

[image]

As you notice, it overlaps the left panel. For the map I am using the Vue2Leaflet library. Thank you in advance.

**SOLUCION:**

```
<v-container>
      <v-card
        class="pa-3"
        flat
        height="550px"
        width="100%"
      >
        <l-map style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: sticky !important;" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
            <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
            <l-marker :lat-lng="markerLatLng" ></l-marker>
        </l-map>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
```

add position:sticky !important; in the style.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you found any solution ?

Comment: @JonathanChaput I have added the solution